# Starting a command in a new screen session doesn't work

Tags: linux, command-line, display, terminal, gnu-screen

I want to execute a command in a new screen session (and detach from it) but I don't get it to work. I tried to start a process in a new screen session and detach from it with this:

```
screen -d -m mycommmand
```

But when I try to attach to that screen session with

```
screen -r
```

I get the message "There is no screen to be resumed". I also tried to start a command in a new screen session with

```
screen mycommand
```

When I do that, a new screen session starts but the command doesn't get executed.

The command is a .sh script that starts a game server but the game server doesn't start.

[Edit]
Because some people asked for the exact command, here it is:
It's a bash script that should start a minecraft server in a seperate screen session.

```
./startServer.sh
```

Here is the .sh script:

```
cd "/home/tim/minecraft/survivalServer"
screen -S "minecraft-server-1-14-4" -m -d /home/tim/java/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -jar /home/tim/minecraft/survivalServer/minecraft_server.1.14.4.jar nogui
```

Now, the problem is, that when I run the script it fails to create the new screen session. Why is that?

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try it without the -d and see what happens.  I'm guessing that something is causing mycommand to exit prematurely.

Comment: leaving out the -d changes nothing. The command doesn't get executed.

Comment: Does the command without `screen` (i.e. `/home/tim/java/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -jar /home/tim/minecraft/survivalServer/minecraft_server.1.14.4.jar nogui`) start the server as expected?

Comment: No, it only starts the server without the screen command. Like I said I dont know why but the screen command doesnt seem to do what it should do...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to launch a nested, detached screen instance inside a detached screen instance. Your script contains the line:

```
screen -S "minecraft-server-1-14-4" -m -d /home/tim/java/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -jar /home/tim/minecraft/survivalServer/minecraft_server.1.14.4.jar nogui
```

This launches screen, names the screen session `minecraft-server-1-14-4` then launches minecraft and detaches. But you are also attempting to run `screen -d -m ./startserver.sh`. So, before the screen session is created in the script you are already running the script inside a detached screen session. This... doesn't tend to work so well.

It's functionally the same as this:

```
wolferz@khaos ~ $ screen -m -d screen -S 'mysession' -m -d top
wolferz@khaos ~ $ screen -r
There is a screen on:
        24850.mysession (07/24/2019 10:47:46 PM)        (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

What you want to do is run the script directly. Just do `./startserver.sh`. That should drop you back at the prompt. You can then attach to your minecraft console by doing `screen -r` as normal.

Comment: I was going to say this and more, but I won't duplicate your answer. The "more" part is: in my tests `screen -m -d top` is different than `screen -d -m top`; the latter seems right but the OP has `-m -d` in the script. I wonder if it adds to the problem.

Comment: I attempted this with `-d -m` as well. Similar result (no dead session... but also no detached session). The [screen manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) specifically shows `-d -m` and `-D -m`. But there is definitely a difference between the two orders. I suspect that the `-m` flag gets ignored if `-d` is first.

Comment: Yes, with nested `screen`s I get no difference, it doesn't work either way. I meant non-nested. Let's wait for the OP, maybe your solution is enough. My point: if it's not, the OP should try `-d -m` in the script.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to start the script directly but it doesnt create the new screen session...

Comment: @TimKluge Please read the comments about `-m -d` vs `-d -m` (above). Do they help?

Comment: no unfortunately not...